# Set minimum length restriction to Password Validation - Regular Expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a regular expression for validating passwords.

`/[\w\d]*(([0-9]+.*[A-Za-z]+.*)|[A-Za-z]+.*([0-9]+.*))/`

This regex matches any words which contain letters and numbers in them.

I want to add a minimum length restriction as well, I got to know we can use `{4,}` to add a minimum length of 4.

But I am not able to figure out how to add this minimum length to the whole expression.

**For example:**
The above regex matches `p12` as valid.

I dont want it to match words with letters and numbers with a length of less than 4.

I tried this, but this did not work

`/[\w\d]*(([0-9]+.*[A-Za-z]+.*)|[A-Za-z]+.*([0-9]+.*)){4,}/`

Any help with respect to adding minimum length restriction to the whole expression would be appriciated.

Thank you.

Comment: You could improve your question by stating, in words, at the beginning, all the requirements that you wish to enforce with a regular expression. You could then show the regex you came up with to enforce all the requirements other than the minimum length restriction. As it is, readers have to reverse-engineer your regex to figure out the  requirements other than minimum length. It may be that the best approach is not to merely add something to what you already have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `\w` also matches `\d` so this parts `[\w\d]*` can be written as just `\w*`

If you want to match only word characters, you could use for example 2 assertions for the char a-z and a digit.

Using a case insensitive pattern:

```
/^(?=[^\d\n]*\d)(?=[^a-z\n]*[a-z])\w{4,}$/i
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mpaBpy/1)

```js
const regex = /^(?=[^\d\n]*\d)(?=[^a-z\n]*[a-z])\w{4,}$/;
[
  "p12",
  "1234",
  "abcs",
  "p123"
].forEach(s => console.log(`${s} --> ${regex.test(s)}`));
```

Comment: Hi thank you for the help,
I also want the password to have uppercase as well as special characters.

After examining the current regular expression I felt It is better to have upperCase as well as special characters 

for upper I added A-Z, how to make this expression capture special characters as well?

Comment: @EaGLE In that case you can write it like this `^(?=[^\d\n]*\d)(?=[^a-z\n]*[a-z])(?=[^A-Z\n]*[A-Z])(?=[^!@#$\n]*[!@#$])[\w!@#$]{4,}$` See https://regex101.com/r/zNVBkq/1

Comment: Sorry I think you got it wrong 

I meant 
p123 should be a match
P123 should be a match
p@123 should be a match
P@123 should be a match

I am just using '@' as a example for special character, it can be any special character in that place

Comment: @EaGLE Then you can shorten the pattern to `^(?=[^\d\n]*\d)(?=[^a-zA-Z\n]*[a-zA-Z])[\w!@#$]{4,}$` https://regex101.com/r/uTalJT/1

Comment: Any word consisting of uppercase or lowercase characters with numbers OR special characters should be a match 

including special characters is optional, but if the password contains special characters its fine

'Rambo2501' should be a match
'R@mbo2501' should be a match

where as 
'Rambo' shoudnt be a match
Because 'Rambo' doesnt contain any numbers nor special characters

Comment: @EaGLE Then you can exclude and the special cars and the digits in the second assertiong`^(?=[^a-zA-Z\n]*[a-zA-Z])(?=[^\d\n!@#$]*[\d!@#$])[\w!@#$]{4,}$` https://regex101.com/r/0Ahiiw/1